# .NET Core 2.1 - AuthorizationHandler not reached and always return 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I have implemented a custom authorization handler to determinate if user is authorized to edit or delete a ressource.
But the handler is never called and I get always a 401 status code when I try to edit a ressource.

This is my custom Handler :

```
public class MeetingAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SameCreatorRequirement, Meeting>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SameCreatorRequirement requirement, Meeting resource)
    {
        /*if (context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
            int idCreator = Int32.Parse(context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault().Value);
            if(idCreator == resource.CreatedBy.IdUserPreferences)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }*/

        context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class SameCreatorRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

I have also add these line in the configure method :

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MeetingAuthorizationHandler>();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Admin"));
    options.AddPolicy("EditPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new SameCreatorRequirement()));
});
```

In controller, I use this :

```
[Route("Meetings/Edit/{id}")]
[Authorize(Policy = "EditPolicy")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
```

I have read a lot of related post and I can find why it's not working. What's wrong in this code ?

### Edit 1

I have found this at the output (I use Cookie Authentication without identity, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x))

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization was successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ForbidResult:Information: Executing ForbidResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was forbidden.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action RoomScheduling.Controllers.MeetingsController.Edit (RoomScheduling) in 21.4851ms
```

### Edit 2

This is my controller :

```
namespace RoomScheduling.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class MeetingsController : Controller
    {

       /** ------------------- **/

        [Route("Meetings/Edit/{id}")]
        [Authorize(Policy = "EditPolicy")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
        {
            MeetingView meetingView = new MeetingView();

            Meeting meeting = await _context.Meeting
                .Include(m => m.Room)
                .Include(m => m.MeetingType)
                .Include(m => m.CreatedBy)
                //.Include(m => m.UpdatedBy)
                .Include(m => m.Attendees)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .SingleAsync(m => m.IdMeeting == id);

            meeting.UpdatedBy = new UserPreferences();
            meeting.UpdatedBy.IdUserPreferences = GetCurrentUserId();
            meetingView.Meeting = meeting;
            meetingView.Attendees = meeting.Attendees.Select(c => c.Attendant).ToArray();

            ViewBag.RoomId = new SelectList(_context.Room.AsNoTracking().Include(m => m.Area).ToList(), "IdRoom", "Name", meeting.Room.IdRoom, "Area.Name"); //Dropdown list
            ViewBag.MeetingTypeId = new SelectList(_context.MeetingType.AsNoTracking().ToList(), "IdMeetingType", "Name"); //Dropdown list
            ViewBag.AttendeesIdList = new MultiSelectList(_context.Attendees.AsNoTracking().Select(a => a.Attendant).Distinct().ToList(), "", "", meetingView.Attendees);

            return View(meetingView);
        }

       /** ------------------- **/
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your controller pls?

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: Not sure but can you try to put AddSingleton after AddAuthorization pls

Comment: Already tried, but I tried again and not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to authorize against a Resource. Your policy has no knowledge on how to retrieve or access the `Meeting` Resource.

If you want to make decisions in your `AuthorizationHandler` that need to access the `Meeting` object you can inject the `IAuthorizationService` into your controller and call authorize against the policy using your `Meeting` Resource.

```
[Route("Meetings/Edit/{id}")]
[Authorize(Policy = "EditPolicy")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
{
    MeetingView meetingView = new MeetingView();

    Meeting meeting = await _context.Meeting
        .Include(m => m.Room)
        .Include(m => m.MeetingType)
        .Include(m => m.CreatedBy)
        //.Include(m => m.UpdatedBy)
        .Include(m => m.Attendees)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .SingleAsync(m => m.IdMeeting == id);

    // Authorize the user against the EditPolicy using the meeting resource.
    var result = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, meeting, "EditPolicy");
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return Forbid();
    }
    // Do stuff.
}
```

If you wish to not make authorization decisions on the resource you can use a different `AuthorizationHandler<TRequirement>`
For example:

```
public class MeetingAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SameCreatorRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SameCreatorRequirement requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! It's true that I ask myself on how the authorization can retrieve the resource..